# Overriding Metadata in codeigniter template

Tags: codeigniter, metadata

I am a newbie in codeigniter and I am not the first web developer of the project however I discovered in views folder it has template.php which loads in all pages. how can i override the metadata of the header inside views folder which loads the header of the template.php? I wan it to have different metadata.

**Here's the code of Template.php**

```
<title>I Sold My Business - Your one-stop shop for online business brokerage</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="Whether you’re an entrepreneur trying to buy a business online or a broker who wants to sell businesses, I Sold My Business is here to help you. Visit us today!">
<meta name="keywords" content="sold business online, buy business online, sell business online">
<?php echo @$template['framework']; ?>
<?php echo @$template['bootstrap']; ?>
    <?php echo @$template['head']; ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('templates/site/reconvert_style.css'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('templates/site/stylesheet.css'); ?>" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function (d, t) {
  var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  bh.type = 'text/javascript';
  bh.src = '//www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey=rkdoxsrzmxvrsrt6ailjsa';
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
  })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

**Here's the code inside controllers folder home.php**

class Home extends CI_Controller

{

```
public function __construct() 

{

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('business_category_model');

    $this->load->model('franchise_category_model');

    $this->load->model('account_model');

    $this->load->model('country_model');

}



public function index() 

{

    $template = array();

    $template['title'] = "Home";

    $this->load->model(array('business_listing_model', 'featured_business_model', 'franchise_model'));

    $this->load->helper('text');



    $page = array();



    $page['countries'] = $this->country_model->get_all();

    $featured_businesses = $this->featured_business_model->random(3);

    $featured_count = 0;



    foreach($featured_businesses->result() as $index => $featured_business)

    {

        if($featured_business->type == 'business' || $featured_business->type == 'video')

        {

            $page['featured_businesses'][$featured_count] = (array) $this->business_listing_model->get_one($featured_business->business_id);

        }

        else

        {

            $page['featured_businesses'][$featured_count] = (array) $this->franchise_model->get_one($featured_business->business_id);

        }



        $page['featured_businesses'][$featured_count]['f_type'] = $featured_business->type;

        $featured_count++;

    }



    if($featured_businesses->num_rows() < 3)

    {

        $limit = 3 - $featured_businesses->num_rows();

        $random_business = $this->business_listing_model->get_random($limit);



        foreach($random_business->result() as $index => $featured_business)

        {

            $page['featured_businesses'][$featured_count] = (array) (array) $this->business_listing_model->get_one($featured_business->business_listing_id);

            $page['featured_businesses'][$featured_count]['f_type'] = 'business';

            $featured_count++;

        }

    }



    $page['business_categories'] = $this->business_category_model->get_all('', array('business_category_title' => 'asc'));

    $page['franchise_categories'] = $this->franchise_category_model->get_all();



    $template['content'] = $this->template->get_view('home', $page, 'site');



    $this->template->render($template, 'site');

}



public function sell_your_biz()

{



    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $account_type = $this->session->userdata('account_type');



    $account = $this->account_model->get_by_username($username);



    if(strlen($username)==0)

    {   

        $this->template->notification('Please login or create an account to post a listing', 'error');

        redirect('/login/');

    }

    $template = array();

    $template['title'] = "Sell Your Biz";



    $page = array();



    $template['content'] = $this->template->get_view('sell_your_biz', $page, 'site');



    $this->template->render($template, 'site');

}



public function view_reconvert()

{

    $template = array();

    $template['title'] = "Home";



    $page = array();



    $page['countries'] = $this->country_model->get_all();

    $page['business_categories'] = $this->business_category_model->get_all();

    $page['franchise_categories'] = $this->franchise_category_model->get_all();



    $template['content'] = $this->template->get_view('home2', $page, 'site');



    $this->template->render($template, 'site' , 'template_rconvert');

}
```

}

Comment: Try re-phrasing your question and give code examples. There is not such things as "the" template in Code Igniter.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one way of doing it, but you can eg set/define your meta data in your controller as such:

```
 public function index() 

 {

     $template = array();

     $template['title'] = "Home";

     $page['meta_desc'] = "Description here";

     $page['meta_key'] = "Keywords here";
```

Then change the view file to correspond to the same variables:

```
  <meta name="description" content="<?= $meta_desc?>" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$meta_key" />
```